# Android System unable to find fragment while activity recreation when fragment loaded from a lib in sd-card?

Tags: android

I have loaded a fragment from external library, available in sd-card successfully but when android system recreate the activity at that my application crash because android system unable to find fragment class that is available in external library.

Code to load Fragment from External apk.

```
  final String libPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/lib.apk";
        final File tmpDir = getDir("dex", 0);

        final File tmpDir1 = new File(libPath);
        Log.d(TAG, ""+tmpDir1.exists());

        final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        final Class<Fragment> classToLoad = (Class<Fragment>) classloader.loadClass("com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.librarycode2.MyFragment");
```

Error Code

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.dynamic_code_run/com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.librarycode2.MyFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4560)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.librarycode2.MyFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:449)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:33)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:110)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2940)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
at com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4560) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.librarycode2.MyFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.dynamic_code_run-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.dynamic_code_run-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:439)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:33) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:110) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2940) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:149) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:287) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85) 
at com.example.sujeetkumarsinha.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4560) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: Add some code and error log

Comment: Your issue is that after recreation of activity, fragment class is not found & it's getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Yep, but is the solution for this?